# Can I disable the ESC key close in SimpleModal

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

Talking about SimpleModal the jQuery plugin.  Most of the time I think it is a handy feature but I am finding that in a certain case I need to remove it.  What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the escClose option:

> escClose [Boolean:true] Allow Esc
>   keypress to close the dialog?

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: awesome, don't know how I missed that :/