# escClose in simple modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I'm working with simple modal, and I'm trying to prevent the close on escape. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593711/can-i-disable-the-esc-key-close-in-simplemodal) says it should be simple, but this doesn't work for me, am I putting this in the wrong place?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login_modal").modal({
        overlayCss: {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
        },
        containerCss: {
            height: 485,
            width: 385,
            backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6",
            border: '3px solid #d3d5d6',
            fontSize: '10pt',
            color: '#58595b',
            fontFamily: 'sans-Serif',
            fontWeight: '100',
            paddingLeft: 5,
            paddingTop: 5,
            opacity: .94,
            escClose: false,
        },
        onOpen: function (dialog) {
            dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow');
            dialog.data.show(); 
            dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            });
        },
        onClose: function (dialog){
            $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
            dialog.container.fadeOut('200');
            dialog.overlay.fadeOut('200', function () {
                $.modal.close();
            });
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `escClose` is in the wrong place - it's a parameter on the modal itself, not the `containerCss` array. You also have extra commas at the end of your `overlayCss` and `containerCss` property arrays. This sometimes causes issues in browsers. Try this;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login_modal").modal({
        escClose: false,
        overlayCss: {
            backgroundColor: '#000'
        },
        containerCss: {
            height: 485,
            width: 385,
            backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6",
            border: '3px solid #d3d5d6',
            fontSize: '10pt',
            color: '#58595b',
            fontFamily: 'sans-Serif',
            fontWeight: '100',
            paddingLeft: 5,
            paddingTop: 5,
            opacity: .94
        },
        onOpen: function (dialog) {
            dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow');
            dialog.data.show(); 
            dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            });
        },
        onClose: function (dialog){
            $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
            dialog.container.fadeOut('200');
            dialog.overlay.fadeOut('200', function () {
                $.modal.close();
            });
        },
    });
});
```